# How to convert an arithmetic expression of a string type to an integer?

Tags: java, string, kotlin, format, int

This is my code after running this piece of code, I am getting exception:

```
fun main( args : Array<String>) {


    var str:String = "(%d + %d)"
    var str1:String

    var a:Int = 12
    var b:Int = 13

    str1 = String.format(str,12,13)
    var c:Int = str1.toInt()

   print(c)

}
```

**Exception** with stack trace is given below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "(12 + 13)"
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:68)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:638)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
    at MainKotlinKt.main(mainKotlin.kt:13)
```

Please help me to solve.

Comment: See [data structures - Expression evaluation in java - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19926777/expression-evaluation-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kotlin `.toInt()` used for converting string to integer where string must be contain integer value. but you have used expression for converting string to integer.

you can read more from [here](https://bezkoder.com/kotlin-convert-string-to-int-long-float-double/#:%7E:text=Kotlin%20convert%20String%20to%20Int&text=toInt()%20to%20parse%20the,valid%20representation%20of%20an%20Integer.)

but if you want to evaluate an expression, then This can be done with the kotlin script engine.

example:

```
val engine = ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByExtension("kts")!!
engine.eval("val x = 8")
val result = engine.eval("x + 2")
Assert.assertEquals(10, result)
```

and you can get more information from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45094181/can-an-integer-in-kotlin-be-equal-to-an-math-expression)

Comment: of course! I know that. I need to move the line to int in this case. please algorithm.

Comment: in my program the user enters text such as (y = pow (x, 2) + 4 * x). the program should produce a result

Answer (score 0):

Firstly your code is nor right and secondly if you are tring to convert math expression in kotlin then I will say kotlin doesn't have any inbuilt function to evaluate math expression neither `str1.toInt()` will help you in this.

toInt() is used to convert string to integer. for example `"10".toInt() = 10`. So, I will suggest you to do manually after extracting required values from extression.